# How do I read in a matrix of unknown length, without whitespaces?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, scanf

My input file looks like this:

```
1,12,5,14,0
4,6,2,3,24
1,2,3,4,5
```

Every line has the same length, but it's unspecified how many lines there are, and how long they are.
(Maximum size is 20*20).

I need to read them into a 20*20 array, so that if the line is only 2 numbers long, the rest of the array is empty.

How do I do that, while leaving out the `,` characters and while starting in the next line of the array when a newline comes in the file?

Here's my attempt:

```
int matrix[20][20];

for (int i=0; i<19; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<19; j++){
        fscanf(be, "%d,", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
    fscanf(be, "\n");
}
```

Ps: I'm only allowed to use **`<stdio.h>`** and **`<stdlib.h>`**.

Comment: If you are artificially restricted to no allowance for `string.h` and/or `ctype.h`, then you're in for a bumpy road. Whoever laid that restriction doesn't engineer in the real world, so remind yourself of that while you're navigating that highway, taking their name in vain at every pothole. You're going to have to at least try, though. Bring your attempt as a [mcve] failure case, and *specific* questions concerning it, and we may be able to help.

Comment: Where's your code? Try to write your own code and than you might indicate us your issues!

Comment: This is not Homeworkoverflow. Please make an attempt first and read [ask]

Comment: I added my own attempt, but I can see that it clearly won't work.

Comment: I'd suggest asking your teacher for advice, but I would read each line with `fgets` and then read the numbers with `sscanf`.

Comment: Possible approach: (1) read the file char by char (2a) if char is numeric, add it to a buffer (2b) if char is `,` or `\n`, turn the current contents of the buffer into a number and put it in the array (3) also, if char is `\n`, increase your matrix row counter (Edit: Paul's answer is basically detailing this exact approach)

Comment: PS: "Every line has the same length, but it's unspecified [...] how long they are." ;)

Comment: Your example lines do not have same length. They have same number of numbers. That's not the same.

Comment: You cannot use fscanf in that way. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Answer (score 1):

I had this idea. The code below reads a line from the file for each loop cycle and scans it, if it's not a void line. The separator `SEP` is retrieved using the function (implemented into the code) `mystrchr`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * mystrchr(const char * s, char x);

char * mystrchr(const char * s, char x) 
{
    while(*s!=0 && *s!=x) s++;

    return ((!*s)?NULL:(char *)s);
}

int main(void)
{
#define FILENAME "x.txt"
#define ROWS 20
#define MAXEL 20
#define BDIM 10240
#define SEP ','

    int x[ROWS][MAXEL],elr[ROWS], ronum=0,elnum,i,j;
    FILE * fptr;
    char buffer[BDIM],* app;

    /* --- Init the array --- */
    for(i=0;i<ROWS; i++)
        for(j=0;j<MAXEL; j++)
            x[i][j]=0;

    /* --- Open the file --- */
    fptr=fopen(FILENAME,"r");
    if (!fptr)
        return 1;

    /* --- Gets data from file --- */
    while(ronum<ROWS && fgets(buffer,BDIM,fptr)) {
        app = buffer;
        /* Takes only non-void lines */
        if (*app && *app!='\n' && *app!='\r') {
            elnum=0;--app;
            /* Scan the line */
            do {
                if (* ++app ) {
                    x[ronum][elnum++]=strtol(app,NULL,0);
                }

                app = mystrchr(app,SEP);
            } while(app && elnum<MAXEL);

            // -- save the number of element per row
            if (elnum) {
                elr[ronum]=elnum;
                ronum++;
            }
        }
    }


    if (fptr)
        fclose(fptr);

    /* --- Prints data --- */
    for(i=0;i<ronum;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<elr[i];j++) {
            printf("%d ",x[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not just init with `int x[ROWS][MAXEL] = {0};` Also see the `atoi` discussion on the other answer.

Comment: I modified the source code. I used strtol instead of atoi. I' m becoming to think that is possible to use only strtol to solve the question ...

Answer (score 0):

Reading lines of unspecified length can be done using `fgetc` to read character-by-character. In your case you must check each character for the following conditions:

- if you see a `','`, you have seen a number;
- if you see a `'\n'`, you have seen a number *and* you have seen a line.
- you skip each non-digit character;
- you place the digits in a small temporary buffer. once you have seen a number, you can convert it using `atoi`;
- if you are not allowed to use `atoi` you perform `number= number*10 + c-'0';` with `c` the digit for each digit you see.

Comment: Sounds like a very bad and complicated way to perform this task.

Comment: @klutt seeing how this is a homework task and the possible tool set is restricted, I'd have done it the exact same way. Mind adding some information as to why you think this is _very bad and complicated_?

Comment: Please don't recommend anyone to use `atoi`. It is a dangerous and 100% superfluous function. Use `strtol` instead.

Comment: @Lundin, what is the danger?

Comment: @domsson Because it would be way easier to solve with a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf`. Just read the first line, count commas to find out dimensions and then a simple loop with the functions i mentioned. And recommending atoi is not a good thing.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie How do you check if the conversion succeeded?

Comment: "The functions atof, atoi, atol, and atoll need not affect the value of the integer
expression errno on an error. If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined." Wheras the strto... functions set `endptr` to point at the beginning of the passed string in case conversion failed.

Comment: @klutt and @Lundin your recommendations might be valid and important for production code (or anything that is supposed to be used in the real world). However, this is homework and for such, I think it might be good to get down to the nitty-gritty (in other words, use as little help in the form of convenient functions as possible). I also don't see any dangers in the use of `atoi()` et al for such a "project". OP is most likely just (supposed to be) learning about programming fundamentals and the input is well-defined.

Comment: If this was my assignment, I'd probably program (and hand in) two solutions: the one outlined by Paul, then one using `fgets` and `sscanf`. The former, I believe, would be more beneficial to the learning process.

Comment: @domsson If an answer is using "wrong" methods for educational purposes, it should at least state that it does precisely that and why. Also, there are a ton of questions here where the root of the problem is using wrong input methods or unsafe methods in general. Much better to get used to using `strtol` from the start than switching later. If the task was to write a parser of some kind `fgetc` would be nice, but that's not the case here.

Comment: It's exactly as Lundin says. It's best to never learn that function. You could reason the same way with `gets`. Sure, it will work, but why get used to it?

Comment: @lundin, I read "If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned (0L)" so in that respect, the result of `atoi` and `strtol` are the same. So how do you determine if a conversion could be performed? (See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). For `atoi` it reads: "If .. no conversion is performed zero is returned."

Comment: My quote was from the standard. Which also says "Except for the behavior on error, they are equivalent to `atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`". There is no guarantee that `atoi` returns 0 upon error.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Which means that if it returns 0 (not a very unusual number) there's no way of detecting an error. With `strtol` you just do a `if(str == endptr) { /* Handle error */ }`. See C standard 7.22.1.4p7

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the description whether a line may be empty.

Assuming that all lines are non-empty, then this is a quite simple `scanf()` job, but the important point is **never discard the return value of input functions**.

A couple of possible approaches:

- Scan using a pattern of `%d` for the first number of each line (return value 0 means we've read all lines), followed by `,%d` for subsequent numbers on that line.  `scanf()` will return 0 when there's no `,` in the input stream, and we move to the next line.
- Scan using a pattern of `%d%c` to capture the character that follows the number into a variable (e.g. `char sep`).  When the return value is 0, we've read all lines, and break the loop.  When the return value is 2, we can examine `sep` to see whether it is `,` or `\n` and choose whether to advance to the next row.  (If the return value is 1, then the last number was at end-of-file, with no final newline).

If some or all lines might be empty, you'll want to peek whether the first character of the line is a newline (probably with `getc()` and `ungetc()`).  That would indicate an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need only `<stdio.h>`. You can separate the values by reading each line into a buffer with `fgets()`. You can parse each value from the buffer using `sscanf` maintaining an offset from the beginning of the buffer utilizing the `"%n"` specifier to determine the number of characters consumed during each conversion to `int`. You add that number (`+1` to account for the `','`) to your offset for each value converted.

(**note:** ideally given `stdlib.h` you would want to use `strtol` to handle the conversions as it provides full error handling to allow you to determine why a conversion failed and handle the failure, but without `limits.h` and `errno.h` you cannot determine whether under/overflow occurred during conversion (without providing your own `LONG_MIN/LONG_MAX` values) so you are limited to just checking whether characters were converted -- which you can do with `sscanf`)

In your case, first `#define` constants for your number of rows, columns and buffer size, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 20     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS
#define MAXC 1024
```

Now declare your array and buffer and row and column variables, open the filename specified as the first argument to the program and validate it is open for reading (or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is given):

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer to hold each line read */
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}}, row = 0, col = 0;  /* array & bounds */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now read each line in the file into `buf` and declare your variables you will use to track the `offset` from the beginning of `buf`, the number of characters `n` consumed during each conversion, the number of columns in the line `ncol` and the value `val` parsed:

```
    while (row < ROWS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        int offset = 0,     /* offset from beginning of line */
            n = 0,          /* number of characters consumed in conversion */
            ncol = 0,       /* number of columns in line */
            val;            /* value from conversion */
```

Now loop maintaining your offset and convert each value in the line adding it to your array:

```
        while (ncol < COLS && sscanf (buf + offset, "%d%n", &val, &n) == 1) {
            arr[row][ncol++] = val; /* assign val, increment ncol */
            offset += n + 1;        /* update offset + 1 for ',' */
        }
```

Now some housekeeping. If you need to ensure that each row in the array has the same number of columns, set the number of columns based on the number of values parsed in the first row. Then for all other rows, compare against that value to ensure you have an equal number of values per-row:

```
        if (!col)           /* if number of columns not set */
            col = ncol;     /* set to no. columns in 1st row */
        if (ncol != col) {  /* force all other rows to have same no. cols */
            fputs ("error: unequal number of columns.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
```

With all values parsed, simply increment the row counter and go convert your next row worth of values:

```
        row++;      /* increment row count */
    }
```

In essence, that is all you need to do. All that remains is to close the file stream (if not reading from `stdin`) and use the values in the array however you like. A complete example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 20     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS
#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer to hold each line read */
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}}, row = 0, col = 0;  /* array & bounds */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (row < ROWS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        int offset = 0,     /* offset from beginning of line */
            n = 0,          /* number of characters consumed in conversion */
            ncol = 0,       /* number of columns in line */
            val;            /* value from conversion */
        /* loop over each value in line */
        while (ncol < COLS && sscanf (buf + offset, "%d%n", &val, &n) == 1) {
            arr[row][ncol++] = val; /* assign val, increment ncol */
            offset += n + 1;        /* update offset + 1 for ',' */
        }
        if (!col)           /* if number of columns not set */
            col = ncol;     /* set to no. columns in 1st row */
        if (ncol != col) {  /* force all other rows to have same no. cols */
            fputs ("error: unequal number of columns.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        row++;      /* increment row count */
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {     /* output array */
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf (" %3d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

The example simply outputs the values stored in your array and exits.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/2020max.txt
1,12,5,14,0
4,6,2,3,24
1,2,3,4,5
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/read2020max dat/2020max.txt
   1  12   5  14   0
   4   6   2   3  24
   1   2   3   4   5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1339:_When_You_Assume) well formatted data, read a *line* with `fgets()` and then parse it via `strtol()`

```
#define COL_MAX 20
#define ROW_MAX 20
#define CHAR_PER_INTEGER (sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
#define LINE_MAX (ROW_MAX * (CHAR_PER_INTEGER + 1) + 2)

long matrix[ROW_MAX][COL_MAX] = {0};  // better to use named constants than magic numbers

int col = 0; 
int row; 
// for (int i=0; i<19; i++){  Not to 19, but 20
for (row=0; row<ROW_MAX; row++){
  char line[LINE_MAX*2]; // Generous buffer, but not insane size
  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, be) == NULL)) {
    break; // No more lines
  }
  char *s = line;
  for (int j=0; j<COL_MAX; j++){
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    long value = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);
    // no conversion, overflow, unexpected next character
    if (s == endptr || errno || (*endptr != ',' && *endptr != '\n')) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input <%s>\n", line);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    matrix[row][j] = value;
    if (*endptr == '\n') {  // no more in this line
      col = j + 1;
      break;
    }
    s = endptr + 1; // advance past the ','
  }
}

// Use row*col portion of the matrix.
```